# Python datetime pattern matching

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to identify if a string can be cast as a date, according to a list of different formats. Thus, the whole list has to be looped over. If a match is found, that match should be returned. If all attempts return errors, that error should be returned. I'm not quite sure how to do this, my approach can be seen below.

```
_DEFAULT_PATTERNS = ["%d.%m.%Y", "%y-%m-%d"]
try:
    if format == 'default':
        for p in _DEFAULT_PATTERNS:
        try:
            value = datetime.strptime(value, p).date()
        except:
            continue
except Exception:
    return ERROR

return value
```

Comment: Have you looked at [dateutil.parser.parse](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse)? It does exactly that

Comment: you have a slight indentation problem with the nested try and the for loop over the patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Your first choice would be to use `dateutil.parser`. If, however, the parser does not meet your needs, here's a version of your code, tidied up:

```
def parseDate(value):
    PATTERNS = ("%d.%m.%Y", "%y-%m-%d")
    for p in PATTERNS:
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(value, p).date()
        except ValueError:
            continue
    return False # No match found
```

Alternatively, raise an exception if the match is not found (instead of returning `False`). This will make your function more similar to `strptime`:

```
    raise ValueError
```

Comment: Thanks, integrated dateutil.parser and works exactly how I want it to! :)

Comment: Sry, have to take it back..unfortunately even if you parse a time such as "20:08:33", the parse(value).date() does not return an error but just makes it a date

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. First,  unless you provide a pattern, "20:08:33" is not recognized by the proposed function. Second, you say that Artur Spirin's works as it should, but it is an exact copy of mine.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
_DEFAULT_PATTERNS = ["%d.%m.%Y", "%y-%m-%d"]
def is_castable_to_date(value):
    for p in _DEFAULT_PATTERNS:
        try:
            value = datetime.strptime(value, p).date()
            return True
        except:
            pass
    return False
print is_castable_to_date("12-12-12")
print is_castable_to_date("12.12.12")
print is_castable_to_date("12/12/12")
```

Comment: Changed it to return the value or to raise a ValueError but apart from that, works as it should! Thanks!

Comment: How is this different from my solution?